# Multiple game instance

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, multiplayer

I have a method `createGame` on Server which create an instance of a game. What i want is to create another instance of the game for differents clients, but when i create another instance of the game, the first game created does not work anymore.

Here is the code:

```
private void createGame(){

    gameThread.add(new GameThread(playerList, controllers.get(controllerNumber), controllers.get(controllerNumber)));

    gameThread.get(gameNumber).start();

    //just to shift the array of game
    gameNumber++;

    //shift the array of controller
    controllerNumber++;

    clientCounter = 0;

    playerList.clear();

    controllers.add(new ControllerServerSide());
}
```

Why I can't play two games at the same time, if each one is on a different thread?

EDIT:

*GameThread*

```
public class GameThread extends Thread{

private Settings settings;
private Game game;

private static int gamesActive = 0; 

public GameThread(ArrayList<Player> playerList, Observer observer, ObservableInput controllerServer){

    ArrayList<Player> newPlayerList = new ArrayList<>();
    int size = playerList.size(); 

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        newPlayerList.add(playerList.remove(0));
    }

    settings = new Settings("src/main/java/it/polimi/ingsw/ps05/gamelogic/mappa.xml", newPlayerList);
    game = new Game(settings, gamesActive++, observer, controllerServer);

    game.init();

}

public void run(){
    game.play();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

From your code it isn't clear what are the members or what they do.. it's really hard to understand what your code does..
But I'll give it a shot:

Try and see if one of the new threads change the same objects as the old game thread.
Or - and I think that might be the problem - you clear the array/list of players and controllers - which both games use.. so the first game works fine but the second clean those list/arrays and destrying what's in there - so your first game stop working.. check it out.

Comment: I'm sorry for the missing code, but probably it will be too much to post it here. However i'll edit the code cause i did a small change, but the problem it's the same. 
As you can see, the arraylist of controllers isn't cleared and i take a different controller for every game. 
Regarding the playerList, it's elements are copied in a new list inside GameThread, as i show you now in the code, before cleaning it.
I've also checked in Debugger, the two GameThread have different playerList.
There's something that i don't get.

Comment: What happans to the first game after creating the second one? It stops? it crashes? Does the secong game woks?

Comment: The second game works, the first gameThread is set as "Running" in debugger but i can't give it any input.

Comment: could you please add the implementation of game.play()?
Sorry for bothering you :)

Comment: Look.. I read your code too many times and I couldn't find the problem..
The only way to find the problem is to debug line by line and see at real time what are the values of each object what it contains.. For some reason I think that your notify function in the ControllerServerCommand doesn't triggered or maybe the list of observers it should notify become empty after creating the second game.. You sould debug line by line and see the flow of your program.. sorry

Comment: Yeah unfortunately i think it's the only way.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
private void createGame(){

    gameThread.add(new GameThread(playerList, controllers.get(controllerNumber), controllers.get(controllerNumber)));

    gameThread.get(gameNumber).start();

    //just to shift the array of game
    gameNumber++;

    //shift the array of controller
    controllerNumber++;

    clientCounter = 0;

    playerList.clear();

    controllers.add(new ControllerServerSide());
```

Comment: Code is always good but it also helps to include some description/context about how the code addresses the original question.